# How to deserialize class with array of serializable object

Tags: c#, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have class with array of some serialized class (named it elements). I want to serialize this class and then deserialize this. But deserialization is difficult.

Because I don't know type of element of my array before serialized this create two arrays match to elements array. In one (`typeOfElements`) keep type of element and in other (`serializedElemnt`) keep serialized string of elements. But I don't know after deserialized how to create my main elements array. How can I convert type to class to create my main array?

```
[ProtoContract]
class MyClass
{
    .
    .

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    object[] elements;

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string[] SerilizedElements;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    string[] TypeOfElements;

    [ProtoBeforeSerialization]
    void initBeforeSerilize()
    {
        TypeOfElements = new string[elements.Length];

        SerilizedElements = new string[elements.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
                TypeOfElements[i] = elements[i].GetType().ToString();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Serializer.Serialize(ms, elements[i]);
                    SerilizedElements[i] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
        } 
    }

    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    void initAfterSerilize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SerilizedElements.Length; i++)
        {
              Type t = Type.GetType(TypeOfElements[i]);

              using(MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SerilizedElements[i])))
              {
                    //I don't know how to write this line
                    elements[i]=Serializer.Deserialize<t>(ms);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible to do what you're trying to do. But I definitely don't think you should by using strings for your serialized objects. You're trying to encode raw binary data as UTF8, and that may simply fail. So instead of an array of strings maybe try with an array of byte arrays, and drop all the stuff with encoding and decoding. (And you also have a mistake with encoding using UTF8 and decoding using ASCII - I don't think either will work, and using two different encodings will definitely not work.)

Comment: about encoding you are right.
In main project I want create connection between two computer with network.
I have several function with different input argument that I want to call them form another computer.
this array is functions inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "I only know the type at runtime" issue, look at `Serializer.NonGeneric`, which has all the methods you would want for working with a `Type`. The non-generic API is also the primary API on the v2 API, aka `TypeModel`. The string encoding issue has already been noted; if you need strings, base-64 should be used, but personally I'd use a `byte[]`. I would also suggest thinking about whether inheritance can be used instead of unknown types - this is certainly possible if the number of candidate types is finite and known.